# Comodo in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I have this problem with Comodo:

```
   (Reading database ... 143450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cav-linux_x64.deb ...
Unpacking cav-linux (1.1.268025-1) over (1.1.268025-1) ...
Uninstallation succeed!
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cav-linux:
 cav-linux depends on libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1); however:
  Package libssl0.9.8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package cav-linux (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cav-linux
```

Is any simple solution or is better to wait for Comodo updates that fit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit.

Thanks

Comment: Search on the linked duplicate question for "libssl0.9".